# When $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is a plane, $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm reading a book about equation of planes and an way to determinate the equation is to suppose a point $P = (x, y, z)$ And suppose also that $A=(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is in the plane. $P$ is in the plane if the vector $\vec {AP}$ and the direction vectors $\vec {v_1} = (r,s,t) $ and $\vec {v_2} = (m,n,p)$ are linearly dependent. This is the same as saying that the determinant of a matrix that contais these vectors as its lines, is $0$.

$$\begin{vmatrix} x-x_0 & y-y_0 & z-z_0\\r & s & t\\m & n & p \\\end{vmatrix} = 0$$

Solving this, we get the equation of the plane:
$$x\underbrace{(sp-nt)}_{a} + y\underbrace{(tm-pr)}_{b} + \underbrace{z(rn-ms)}_{c} + \underbrace{-x_0(sp-nt) -y_0(tm-pr) - z_0(rn-ms)}_{d}$$
$$ax + by + cz + d = 0$$

Then, he says that $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \neq 0$$

wich is the same as saying that $a$,$b$, anc $c$ are not simulteneosly $0$. He says that if they were, then $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ would be L.D., thus, would not define a plane. I have no idea how to verify that hey would be linearly dependent. Could yous guys help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $a=0, b=0$ and $c=0$, then $sp=nt$, $tm=pr$ and $rn=ms$ and therefore (if $m,n,p$ are distinct from $0$):

$(r,s,t)=(r/m)(m,n,p)=(s/n)(m,n,p)=(t/p)(m,n,p)$

Now, if some of them is zero, we have to do some cases, but it is more annoying than difficult.

(I wanted to post this as a comment, but I have not enough reputation).

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors are linearly dependent if one is a scalar constant times the other. The idea here is that if you place two vectors having different directions with their tails together, there's a unique plane that they both lie in. But if they end up lying on top of each other (that is, they're collinear), then there are infinitely many planes that contain both.

Comment: I know this, but how would this prove that $a$,$b$ anc $c$ are not simulteneosly $0$?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. Conceptually, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are the $x,y,z$-components of the cross-product of $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$. The magnitude of that cross-product vector is the magnitude of $\vec v_1$ times the magnitude of $\vec v_2$ times the sine of the angle between them. If $v_1$ and $v_2$ have nonzero magnitudes and the angle between them is nonzero (and less than 180 degrees), then the cross-product vector won't come out as $(0, 0, 0)$.

Comment: it's because I'm only allowed to use cross product in an orthogonal coordinate system, but this method works in every coordinate system. So I need to prove it in another way.

Comment: So you're saying that the book gave you a problem and asked you to solve it within certain constraints? You didn't say that before! You are supposed to prove that $(a,b,c) \neq (0,0,0)$ and do it without the cross product. OK, I guess Devilathor was smarter than I at divining your meaning, because he gave the answer, using contraposition: if $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$, then $(r,s,t)$ equals $(m,n,p)$ times a constant.